# CUDA /openCL; rewriting branches as non-branching expression

Tags: c++, optimization, cuda, opencl, gpu

Most of the time a branch is required in a CUDA or OpenCL program, like:

```
for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
{
   if( i % threadIdx.x == 0)
     quantity += i*i;
}
```

the code can always (or at least, most of the time) be rewritten in non-branching style:

```
for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
{
   quantity += i*i* (i % threadIdx.x != 0);
}
```

the tradeoff seems to be either running in a single warp slot versus doing more computations on all the threads (in the second case, the sum is executed always, just that sometimes the value is zero)

Assuming that branching operations will take multiple warp slots for each possible branch, one would expect the second be consistently better than the first, Now my question is; Can i rely on the compiler to optimize 1) into 2) whenever it makes sense, or there is not a broadly-applicable criteria, which implies that it cannot be decided in general which one is better without trying and profiling?

Comment: What order is width? If you know that width is quite large, you should not be iterating through a for loop to do this, as you know which values you are going to be using. `While(i < width) { quantity += i*i; i+= threadIdx.x } would do better...

Answer (score 3):

Modulo operations are reasonably expensive: I am reasonably sure adding in the modulo would use more time than just having a single instruction that only 1 thread executes. Your single branching statement, an `if` with no `else`, will only hang the other threads while that if statment is being executed. Because gpus are optimized for very fast context switching, there should be very little cost for that.

You are advised against using long branching statements though: too much serial computation on the GPU (ie one thread doing all the work) negates the advantage of the parallelism.

Comment: Also, just checking in the CUDA Best Programming guide, making your code easy to use for Branch Prediction is a low priority. There are more important things to optimize generally.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience - it is totally up to the compiler-writers to optimize these sorts of edge cases.

So can I think of any cases where 1) cannot be turned to 2)  ? Here's one: I have written kernels where it was more efficient to run certain pieces of the computations every 10 threads or something like that in which case such an optimization cannot be inferred even though there is a mathematical operation (a divide an subtract) that can yield the same result irrespective of conditional versus "run on all but yield zero results".

However, even given that checking for threadId == 0 is a common enough scenario, I have no idea if it is actually optimized for. I would wager that it depends on the implementation AND even the device itself (CPU vs GPU).

You will have to try it to really find out what works best, not just because of the reason above but also because the work scheduler might behave differently based on how expensive it is to schedule/start/stop a set of threads as opposed to having them all run (and most provide a zero/identity result).

Hope this helps!

Comment: so, in your experience, can you make some recommendations regarding if should i always try to write code in style 2, assuming the worst scenario? or can that have unintended consequences?

Comment: I cannot justify one over the other in all cases - which is my point. I would probably use 1) if I was doing something like a reduction of something manageable on a CPU device but 2) if I was on a GPU because of the cost of branching on older hardware - if that scenario was valid. The factors to consider are - device type, how non-parallel the computation is, is it feasible to split the compute into multiple kernels (perhaps the reduce) and finally if the branching overhead on all hardware for the selected device type is acceptable. But IMO, experimentation would always be recommended.

Comment: to be clear, i'm talking in the specific case of GPU devices, obviously there is no gain with CPU because there is a lot of branch prediction and pipelining helping with the latency hiding

Comment: now i see that my question was a bit vague regarding the platform, i've added the `gpu-programming` tag to make it clearer

Comment: Given that you're going to be launching thousands of threads on the GPU and perhaps continue on after doing this non-parallelized bit, I would go with 2) but only after trying 1) also on the target hardware. But I'm paranoid, so you may choose to skip the experimentation. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have many memories about CUDA, but why don't you parallelize your loop ? You should use atomic operations[1] to add your computation. I hope this will help you! Sorry if it's not the case.

1. Atomic Operations: http://supercomputingblog.com/cuda/cuda-tutorial-4-atomic-operations/

Comment: This is inside a kernel - each thread is executing the full loop. The comment doesn't make sense.